# jQuery injecting data in ajax global event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to inject data in my ajax requests, but it fails and I don't know why. I tried to look at the jQuery source code, but still can't find why it doesn't work, Any help appreciated. Here is the code :

```
$('#someElement').ajaxSend(function(e, req, options) {
    options.data += (options.data.length > 0 ? '&' : '') + '__token=' + $('input#requestToken').val();
}).ajaxSuccess(function(e, req, options, data) {
    if (data.nextToken) {
        $('input#requestToken').val(data.nextToken);
        delete data.nextToken;
    }
});
```

The response looks like this :

```
{
   "response":
   {
      "code":0,
      // ...
   },
   "nextToken":"4ded26352b3d44"
}
```

A typical request would be, for example :

```
$.getJSON(url, {something:'value'}, function(data) {
   if (data.response.code != 0) {
      // handle code
   }
});
```

The problem is that, the data sent is "`something=value`"; the modified `data` is not sent.

** **EDIT** **

The current request data is

```
something: value
```

and should be

```
something: value
__token: 4ded288eec1f56
```

In the `ajaxSend` event callback, if I print the value of `options.data` after modifying it, the value is "`something=value&__token=4ded288eec1f56`", but "`__token=4ded288eec1f56`" is **not** sent. Why isn't it sent in the request?

But more specifically, how to "fix" this, if even possible?

Comment: It is very hard to understand what the problem is.  Can you explain more about what you *want* to happen and what actually *does* happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that by the time jQuery decides to call the "ajaxSend" callback, the parameters have already been used to prepare the request. Thus, changing them in that handler has no effect.

*edit* — given the answer from @mikermcneil I'm not sure this is right. The jQuery "ajax" method is, to say the least, complicated. His sample page certainly *seems* to work, which confuses me but probably should just help me realize how little I know about jQuery internals :-)

Comment: yes, I think that's what happens. though I don't know why, nor how to go around that "limitation"...

Comment: That code (the jQuery "ajax" function and all its friends) is very hard to understand. I'm not even sure how parameters get into the XHR object for POST requests, though I think I see where it happens for GET requests. I have not tried to do what you're doing here, so I don't have any suggestions unfortunately.

Comment: Oh wait - you might see what the value of "options.url" is.  It may be that you can change that, but again I'm not sure.

Comment: that's an idea... I'll try that

Comment: it works! In conclusion, one *can* modify the `data` setting, but the value has already been appended to the `url`, so modifying the `url` does work. Also, the `data` is the same passed to the `ajaxSuccess` event family, so `data` should also be sync'ed if all the request params needs to be present in the response event.

Answer (score 2):

-edit

Update-- the trouble is with getJSON.

It looks like, while jQuery does fire the ajaxSend event in both cases, it doesn't actually use the changed data variable with getJSON like it does with post.

Replace getJSON with $.post to solve your problem (that's what I'm doing in the example I linked to below).

-edit-
Well, I set up a version of it here:

http://abolition.me/toys/View/attachAjax.html
(see the console)

I'm having the server send back whatever it got and it's saying:
__token: "toketoketoke"
key: "val1"
key2: "val2"

So it looks like modifying the request data is working-- what does your handler look like server-side?

I'm looking into it-- first and foremost though (and I mistake I made as I tried to replicate the problem), have you checked that you're assigning your event after the document is ready? ($(function(){  });)

Comment: Good question, and yes I do. Everything works, except that weird issue

Comment: Ahh --- POST would involve a different mechanism for parameter passing than GET, but I can't figure out how/where in the jQuery code the POST parameters are handled.

Comment: See @Pointy's answer for an explanation why it works with $.post and not $.getJSON

Comment: Yep that's it-- I tried it with $.get and got the same results as $.getJSON

Comment: yes, this is interesting... so... I need to check if the query is POST or GET in the global event, and set the `options.data` in POST and `options.url` in GET, then.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that your JSON response is correct:

```
{
  "response":
  {
  "code":0,  <-- this is not valid
  },
  "nextToken":"4ded26352b3d44"
}
```

valid should be:

```
{
  "response":
  {
  "code":0
  },
  "nextToken":"4ded26352b3d44"
}
```

To validate your JSON response you can use:

[The JSON Validator](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: I removed the unnecessary, unrelated response data. I forgot the comma. Please don't bug about that. The response is generated by `Zend_Json::encode()`

Answer (score 0):

You are only passing data within the second parameter in your getJSON call {something:'value'}. Any data you want to send to the server must be included there. Thus, the __token must be included in that parameter.

The third parameter in the getJSON call is the call back function. The parameter passed to that function is the response from the server.

```
$.getJSON(
    url,
    {
        something:'value',
        __token: 'token value'
    ,
    function(response) {
        if (response.response.code != 0) {
        // handle code
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: since some requests are done inside jQuery plugins, etc. and request tokens needs to be "validated" and "updated" quite often, modifying the jQuery plugins to send the token is quite *not* an option.